# Is the dual of a normed space, a Hilbert space?

Tags: hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $V$ be a normed complex vector space. The dual $V^*$, is defined as the set of bounded linear operators from $V$ into $\mathbb C$.

$V^* = L(V,\mathbb C)$

It can be shown that $V^*$ equipped with the operator norm

$||A|| = \sup_{v \in V} \frac{||A(v)||}{||v||}$

is a Banach space. Is it correct to assume that $V^*$ is also a Hilbert space?

Roughly thinking, I believe it can be proven that the norm on the dual space satisfies the parallelogram identity and then it follows that a sesquilinear inner product can be defined on $V^*$ promoting it into a Hilbert space.

[Edit]

Proof that the norm on $V^*$ satisfies the parallelogram identity:

Take any $A,B \in V^*$

$||A+B||^2 =  \sup_{v \in V} \frac{||(A+B)(v)||}{||v||} \sup_{u \in V} \frac{||(A+B)(u)||}{||u||}$
$ =  \sup_{v \in V} \frac{||(A+B)(v)||^2}{||v||^2} $

then

$||A+B||^2+||A-B||^2 =  \sup_{v \in V} \frac{||(A+B)(v)||^2}{||v||^2}+ \sup_{v \in V} \frac{||(A-B)(v)||^2}{||v||^2}$
$= \sup_{v \in V} \frac{1}{||v||^2}(||(A+B)(v)||^2+||(A-B)(v)||^2)$
$= \sup_{v \in V} \frac{1}{||v||^2}(||A(v)+B(v)||^2+||A(v)-B(v)||^2)$

notice $A(v),B(v) \in \mathbb C$, and the norm in the complex numbers (defined as the $\sqrt{Real^2+Imaginary^2}$) satisfies the parallelogram law, then

$||A+B||^2+||A-B||^2 = \sup_{v \in V} \frac{1}{||v||^2}(2 ||A(v)||^2+2||B(v)||^2)$
$=2||A||^2+2||B||^2 $

Is it wrong?

Comment: I wonder if there even is an instance where $V^*$ Hilbert does not imply $V$ Hilbert.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli $V$ need not be complete. For normed spaces, that is the only thing that can happen. For a locally convex $V$, $V^{\ast}$ is a Hilbert space if and only if $V$ is a pre-Hilbert space (topology induced by a positive semidefinite hermitian form, not necessarily Hausdorff). If we look at spaces that aren't locally convex, other things can happen, e.g. for $V = L^2([0,1]) \times L^{1/2}([0,1])$ we have $V^{\ast} \cong L^2([0,1])$.

Comment: @lagrange.el.ciencia One major flaw in your work is that $$\sup_v f(v)+\sup_vg(v)=\sup_{v,w} (f(v)+g(w))\ne\sup_{v} (f(v)+g(v))$$ the two $v$-s in the two sups are different (similar thing happens for the product, but you squaring works regardless by the fact that it is a strictly increasing function on the codomain of the functions you are sup-ing).

Comment: @G.Sassatelli, indeed I am suspicious about that part of playing 'round with the sup's.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli. I realize you're right. The squaring works, but the sum of the sup's is wrong. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is definitely not true in general. For example, if $V = L^p(X,\mu)$ with the $L^p$ norm when $p \neq 2$ then $V^{*}$ is isometric to $L^q(X,\mu)$ with $\frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{q} = 1$ and it well-known that $L^q(X,\mu)$ with the $L^q$ norm ($q \neq 2$) is not a Hilbert space because it doesn't satisfy the parallelogram identity.

Comment: Please, can you be more explicit? What does it mean $L^p$ in words? I am newbie, therefore, not acquainted with the standard notation.

Comment: Wikipedia has a good entry: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space